# does install4j updater support multi delivery channels (stable / beta / nightly)?

Tags: java, install4j

I am using install4j to package my java application. I distribute installers for all platforms along portable archives. So far, I have been using a self-developed update mechanism which has some limitations mostly related to permission rights. I am considering delegating the update process to Install4j but I am not sure it can deal with my needs (at least I haven't found how to achieve what I need). My app has the following feature:
- user can select a delivery channel (stable / beta /nightly)
- the app has the logic to check if an update is available based on the channel and to point to the right new artefacts
- my app fails the update process in some cases because of writing rights

Can Install4J manage such a use case? I would need to call install4j updater with all the update parameters as I don't think I can't achieve what I want with a single update.xml file. I could not find how to do it reading the documentation but considering multi-delivery channels is quite common I thought I might have missed it.

Thank you in advance for your help and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update downloader in install4j is just a template, you can modify it according to your own needs.

In your case, you need a different `updates.xml` for each channel, for example `updates_stable.xml`, `updates_beta.xml` and `updates_nightly.xml`.

The update downloader template is already set up to deal with variable URLs for `update.xml`. If you locate the "Check for update" action, you will see that its "Update descriptor URL" property is set to

```
${installer:updatesUrl?:${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}}
```

This means that if the installer variable `updatesUrl` is specified, that value is used. If not (this is the default), the content of the compiler variable `sys.updatesUrl` is used which is the value that is specified on the "Installer->Update options" step.

If you start the update downloader with the argument

```
-VupdatesUrl=<URL for updates.xml>
```

the installer variable is set and will be used.

Alternatively, you can use a persistent installer variable that can be set in the installer, for example with a "Set a variable" action. In that case, the variable has to be written to the response file. The "Register for response file" property of the "Set a variable" action has to be selected, or you have to call

```
context.registerResponseFileVariable("updatesUrl");
```

Then, you have to add a "Load a response file" action to the "Startup" node of the update downloader and the variable will be set automatically with its persisted value.

Yet another option is to use the user-specific preference store, in that case you would use a "Save installer variables to the Java preference store" action in the installer and a "Load installer variables from the Java preference store" action in the update downloader to persist the value of the installer variable. The latter approach has the advantage that you can use the API

```
com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.saveToPreferenceStore(...)
```

in your own code to change the variable value without elevated privileges.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in my app each time the user select a new channel (stable/beta/..) I should update `updatesUrl` by calling for example `com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.saveToPreferenceStore(Map.of("updatesUrl", "http://www.updatesStable.xml");)`  then in other places of my code I call the standalone update downloader using `com.install4j.api.launcher.ApplicationLauncher`, is that correct ?  
Also for my info, is the `updatesUrl` stored inside the .install4j folder ?  
Thank you

Comment: Correct. If you use the preference store method, the value will be stored in the Java preference story which is not inside the .instal4j folder. On Windows, for example, this is in the registry.

Comment: I tried to call `saveToPreferenceStore` but I was not sure which kind of map I was supposed to pass as arguments as map<String, String> is not possible. Hence I tried to have an example calling 'loadFromPreferenceStore(false)' but this throws an error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: %appdata%\Local\Temp\install4jNative\8176\windows-x64\i4jparams.conf (The system cannot find the file specified)`. Any idea ?

Comment: Seems the error was thrown because was launched from the IDE, from the app itself it returns null, I guess because I haven't called saveToPreferenceStore() yet. 
I also tried to call `saveToPreferenceStore` not from the IDE, this time I have a different error message  `java.io.IOException: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: flush(): Backing store not available`

Comment: I had to set userSpecific = True to avoid this error, all works just fine now. I have a last question if I may, would that approach support also multi install. For example if I have 2 medias produced with install4J, an installed version (Windows setup) and a Windows archive. I want the installed version to store "updatesUrl"="stable" while the archive to store "updatesUrl"="beta". Could both be stored and retrieved in a consistant manner using the media ID or something else ?

Comment: On General Settings->Variables, you can define a compiler variable `mediaPrefix` with the value  `${compiler:sys.mediaId}`. Then you can get this value in the launcher via `Variables.getCompilerVariable("mediaPrefix")`. In the installer, you can use `${compiler:sys.mediaPrefix}` in text fields to refer to this value or call `context.getCompilerVariable("mediaPrefix")` in a script.