# install4J, how to correctly pass `updatesUrl` to the updater via the Java preference store?

Tags: java, install4j

I am trying to implement multi-channels (deb/beta/stable) update for my app following recommendation made in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109803/does-install4j-updater-support-multi-delivery-channels-stable-beta-nightly).

I have done the following steps:

1. create a compiler variable `mediaID=${compiler:sys.mediaId}`
2. when user of my app changes it release channel preference, the ollowing function is called: `mediaID = Variables.getCompilerVariable("mediaID"); Variables.saveToPreferenceStore(Map.of("updatesUrl", xmlURL), mediaID, true);`
3. when user decide to update the following function is called:
   `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess(UPDATER_APPLICATION_ID, null, ....)`  but this throws an error (exit value = 1):

[image]

Based on the error message, it seems that the updater does not find the `updatesUrl` variable but just before the call to the function I logged the output of `com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.loadFromPreferenceStore(mediaID, true);` and I got as a result `{updatesUrl=https://github.com/akasolace/HO/releases/download/dev/updatesDEV.xml}` which is the legit URL, so it seems updatesUrl was properly stored.

Now, I am a bit confused on how this should work. Me for example, I am running 2 version of the app in parralel and my setup is something like:

- mediaID 1, release channel Stable
- mediaID 2,  release channel Dev

on my system I will have variable `updatesUrl` store in 2 differents package something like:

```
{(1, "updatesUrl"): "...updatesSTABLE.xml", (2, "updatesUrl"): "...updatesDEV.xml"}
```

Now, in install4J, I added the action "Load installer variable from the Java preference store" and I see package name default to `${compiler:sys.applicationId`. This leads to the following question:

- I believe applicationID unique for the app and mediaID different for each media. To achieve what I want I believe I need the updater to use as package name, the media ID of the media that called it. I mean if the updater is called from media ID x , I need it to look at the variable "updatesUrl" from package x. Is it doable or am I getting lost?

[Edit] I tried to set package name of "Load installer variable from the Java preference store" to `${compiler:sys.mediaId` but this throws instead

[image]
Thank you in advance for your help.

with the following stack trace

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.install4j.runtime.installer.Application.runApplicationInProcess(Application.java:64)
com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.apiimpl.ApplicationLauncherImpl$1.run(ApplicationLauncherImpl.java:57)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.loadFromPreferenceStore` does not set installer variables, it returns a map with the variable values. This is intended for use in your application.

What you have to do is to add a "Load installer variables from the Java preference store" action to the "Startup" node in in the update downloader. In that way, the `updatesUrl` installer variable is actually set to the value from the preference store.

Comment: This is what I did as I mentioned in my question `I added the action "Load installer variable from the Java preference store" and I see package name default to ${compiler:sys.applicationId}`

Comment: Still for debug purposed I configured the "Load installer variables from the Java preference store" action by hardcoding the package I put a value of 56 which is the mediaID which was used when I stored `updatesUrl`in the java preference store.

Comment: In my app if I call `loadFromPreferenceStore("56", true);` just before the update I got `{updatesUrl=https://github.com/akasolace/HO/releases/download/dev/updatesDEV.xml}` which is the valid url but still the updater does not manage to load it from the store despite having it hardcoded as it throws the error I show in my question (internal error ....).

Comment: The error dialog shows that the used URL is empty. Try replacing the "Update descriptor URL" property of the "Check for update" action with ${installer:updatesUrl} and look at the log file output of the update downloader.

Comment: I found my error: the "Load installer variable from the Java preference store" action was not in the startup node. I should have read the doc more carefully. I need more tests but so far it seems to work perfectly.  thanks a lot for you valuable help !